# Fade html dom elements on scroll

Tags: html, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Can't seem to spot the error here. I want the ".title" class to fade in and out when the ".top" class is scrolled to 150px

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".top").on("scroll", function(){
          if($(this).scrollTop = 150){
            $(".title").fadeToggle(1000);
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: If my answer does not help you, then insert your html and css here to see the structure of the elements, and thereby give you the right solution

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it necessary?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
        $(".title").fadeToggle(1000);
      } else {}
  }); 
});
```

```css
.top {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: green;
}

.title {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <p class="title">This is title</p>
</div>
```